# merge two files based on partial matching

Tags: bash, unix, awk, merge, match

I have two files

FileA.txt

```
ID
479432_Sros_4274
330214_NIDE2792
517722_CJLT1_010100003977
257310_BB0482
...
```

FileB.txt (The ** is only to help you to identify the matches)

```
members   category
6085.XP_002168109,**479432_Sros_4274**,4956.XP_002495993.1,457425.SSHG_03214,51511.ENSCSAVP000  P
7159.AAEL006372-PA,**257310_BB0482** J
**517722_CJLT1_010100003977**,701176.VIBRN418_17773,9785.ENSLAFP00000010769,28377.ENSACAP00000014901,4081.Solyc03g120250.2.1,3847.GLYMA18G02240.1 U
500485.XP_002561312.1,1042876.PPS_0730,222929.XP_003071446.1,**330214_NIDE2792**  S
...
```

Expected output

Output.txt

```
ID  category
479432_Sros_4274  P
330214_NIDE2792  S
517722_CJLT1_010100003977  U
257310_BB0482  J
...
```

I have tried some code in awk and R based on answers to other questions, but I could not get the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  print "ID  category"
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
{
  for(i in a){
    if(match($0,i)){
      print i,$NF
    }
  }
}
'  Input_filea   Input_fileb
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                              ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  print "ID  category"              ##Printing string ID, category here.
}                                   ##Closing BLOCK for BEGIN section.
FNR==NR{                            ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when 1st Input_file is being read.
  a[$0]                             ##Creating an array named a whose index is $).
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i in a){                      ##Traversing through array a with for loop.
    if(match($0,i)){                ##Checking condition if match is having a proper regex matched then do following.
      print i,$NF                   ##Printing variable i and $NF of current line.
    }
  }
}
'  Input_filea   Input_fileb        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the output is not the expected. The output looks like:
```
ID category
ID P
ID S
ID U
ID J
...
```
it seems ID did appear many times in file2 (I checked with grep). Then I changed the column header ID for "name_of_identifier" which is not present in file2 and then the output file only contains 1 row with the headers:
```
name_of_identifier category
```

Comment: @palomo11, my code was written and tested with provided examples if you have different data than shown one then kindly do edit your post with data which is more near to your data, lemme know once edit done.

Comment: Ah, I just double checked. I had to replace "." for "_" in 1 of the files to match with the another one. Now it works well! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is one way of doing it:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                  # process file1
    if(FNR==1)             # print header, no newline
        printf $1
    a[$1]                  # hash data
    next
}
{                          # process file2
    if(FNR==1)             # print the other half of the header
        print OFS $2
    for(i in a)            # loop all items in hash
        if($1 ~ i)         # check for partial match
            print i,$2     # if found, output
}' file1 file2             # mind the order
```

Output (in file2 order, notice the partial match of in the last line of output, left as a warning):

```
ID category
479432_Sros_4274 P
257310_BB0482 J
517722_CJLT1_010100003977 U
330214_NIDE2792 S
ID S
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the output is not the expected. The output looks like:
```
ID category
ID P
ID S
ID U
ID J
...
```
it seems ID did appear many times in file2 (I checked with grep). Then I changed the column header ID for "name_of_identifier" which is not present in file2 and then the output file only contains 1 row with the headers:
```
name_of_identifier category
```

Comment: Ah, I just double checked. I had to replace "." for "_" in 1 of the files to match with the another one. Now it works well! Thanks!

Comment: _it seems ID did appear many times in file2_ Yes, that's why left it as a warning in the answer instead of fixing it. Easy fix is to add a `next` after the `printf`, ie. `if(FNR==1){printf $1; next}` or skip both `FNR==1` and `print` the header in the `BEGIN` block as @RavinderSingh13 did.